# WSO2 API publisher and store issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I need add multiple API publisher and store but I don't want to use WSO2 UI to add one by one.
How to use program to add all API publisher and store?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APIs published by WSO2. Take a look at their [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html).

Before you make an API calls, you to have call [following APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#guide) to receive `scope` & `access_token`:

1. Register your application using `/register`.(the client from which you will be making API call needs to be verified.)
2. Get `access_token` using `/token` API.